# Get collection not working but query does

Tags: magento-1.9, collection

I don't know why this:

```
$attributeCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('myext/attributelist_collection')
//$attributeCollection = Mage::getModel('myext/attributelist')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('to_export', array('eq' => 1))
    ->getSelect()->order('order DESC');
```

Isn't working, when the query I get with `__getSelect()` is correct and works when I execute it directly in the console.

The line commented is another try that doesn't work.

any idea?

Comment: Is that any error show when you try above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you call `getSelect()`, it'll return a Zend_Db_Select object instead of a Magento collection.

Break it into two statements: one for getting the collection, and the second for adding custom sql expressions. Try this:

```
$attributeCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('myext/attributelist_collection')
    ->addFieldToFilter('to_export', array('eq' => 1));

$attributeCollection->getSelect()->order('order DESC');
```